# How can a single nginx virtual server deal with both port 80 and 443?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have a config file with a virtual server setup, this is running on port 443 for ssl. I would also like this same virtual server to handle non ssl traffic on port 80.

I was hoping to do the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    ...
}
```

It looks like the ssl options below these settings are causing problems for the non ssl traffic.

Comment: You didn't show full config, but if you happen to have `ssl on` directive in `...` block — remove it.

Comment: `ssl on` is there but if I remove this wont ssl requests stop working?
I am just looking to handle non ssl requests not stop ssl requests

Comment: `ssl` flag in `listen` will handle it. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server

Comment: Thats amazing, thank you. If you add it as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Remove `ssl on;` directive.

`ssl` flag in `listen` directive is exactly what you need.

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server

Answer (score 45):

Yes, of course.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  # force https-redirects
  if ($scheme = http) {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Here is my post, name "[Nginx Configuration for HTTPS](https://lihaimei.wordpress.com/2014/11/10/nginx-configuration-for-https/)" which contains more info.

Comment: The linked article only prohibits the use of the `if` directive inside location blocks for non-rewrite statments. It is perfectly safe to use `if` inside a server block, particularly if the 'if' is limited to a return statement. Read the article before insinuating it says something it doesn't.

Comment: @Haimei, is there any benefit to putting both 80 and 443 ports in the same server block vs having a server block for each port?